# JavaScript event listeners

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My friend made it so that on their page you can't right click on the pictures to save them. After inspecting the html it looks like this is done with JavaScript to bind the `mousedown` event. If I disable JavaScript, then I can right click and save the pictures, but I want to try to see if I can do it without disabling JavaScript. I tried using the JavaScript console to set different values and functions to null, but it didn't work.

I set a breakpoint on the `mousedown` event and whenever I right click on a picture this is what happens.

```
 return document.addEventListener("mousedown", (function(e) {
        return _this.onMouseDown(e);
      }), true);
```

Why is it necessary to bind the `mousedown` event every time a user clicks the button? Shouldn't it only have to be bound once at the beginning?

I tried using `removeEventListener` but it didn't do anything. How can I re-enable right click on the pictures?

This is [the page](http://ameblo.jp/maofish/image-11055784672-11563232027.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run a browser that has a preference that prevents the web page from blocking right-click and set that preference (such as Firefox or Chrome).  I can right-click save any of your friend's images in my default configuration of Firefox.

FYI, there are much more effective ways of doing right-click blocking than your friend is using (including ways that work even when Javascript is disabled), but no scheme can block anyone from taking the images.  The images can always be copied via screen capture, grabbing from the browser cache, grabbing the image URL from the page source, etc...

A popular photo service uses a right-click deterrent by putting a scaled transparent gif image over a background image that is the actual image you see.  When the user right-clicks they get the transparent gif, not the background image they're looking at.  I call it a small deterrent because it's still easily bypassed by any determined thief.   This scheme works even when javascript is disabled and even works in browsers like Firefox that prevent apps from blocking right-click because it doesn't use any javascript and because it feeds right-click the blank gif, not the image of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can see whether there are any other events attached to the document. Use[Visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event)

Also addEventListener is old way of attaching events, if you could use jquery then you can easily bind/unbind events using bind() and unbind() methods.

Comment: addEventListener is NOT an old way of attaching events.  It's THE standard way of doing so.  jQuery just uses addEventListener itself.

Comment: I already tried Visual event. It shows some things but it doesn't seem to show anything about the pictures.